# How can i change a list of string name In vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, soap, vb.net-2010

i have a `WebMethod` that you pass a SQL Query for execution and return a list of string

- The query comes from the client side so i don't know what it is

Here is the `webMethod`

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function ExecQuery() As List(Of String)

    Dim result As New List(Of String)
    Dim sqlConn As New sqlConn........
    Dim queryString As String = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_name'
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, sqlConn)
    sqlConn.Open()
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        For i As Integer = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
            result.Add(reader.Item(reader.GetName(i)))
        Next

    End While
    Return result

End Function
```

*This code return a list of string as follow*

[image]

*i don't have enough experience doing this*

**QUESTION**

What is the best way of organizing this

- How can i change `<string>` To `<column_name>` and wrap them with `Unique Name`

  i used to create a `Class` and instead of `list (of string)` i used the class reference

and i get a list as follow

```
 <className>
     <col1>val1<col1>
     <col2>val1<col1>
 </className>
 <className>
     <col1>val2<col1>
     <col2>val2<col1>
 </className>
```

and then i loop in javascript using this class name

Comment: I am surprised 'SELECT * FROM emp ' is returning XML.

Comment: i thought web service always return a list of the data type in XML when you test it

Comment: OK good answer.  Have you looked at WCF and DataContract.  I don't know how to do what you are asking but WCF is considered more configurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this needs to be completely dynamic, then (as @Jeremy suggested) return your own XML. Have the webmethod return `String`, not `List(Of ...)`. Create your own XML string:

```
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
While reader.Read()
    sb.Append("<record>")
    For i As Integer = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
        sb.AppendFormat("<field name=""{0}"">", reader.GetName(i))
        sb.Append(reader(i).ToString())
        sb.Append("</field>")
    Next
    sb.Append("</record>")
End While

Return sb.ToString()
```

Parse the XML in your Javascript code using DOM methods.

Comment: Also, don't say `reader.Item(reader.GetName(i))`; just say `reader(i)`.

Comment: thanks .. but this is the problem i don't know the number or the name of columns to create a class that fits ... please read the question one more time

Comment: looks promising i will try this and let you know